# Simplify implementation of Collections.sort on custom type

Tags: java, generics, sorting

I need to sort a List of Job which I currently do with:

```
List<Job> jobs = new ArrayList<Job>();
Job job0 = new Job("a", 1, Arrays.asList("t0"));
Job job1 = new Job("a", 2, Arrays.asList("t0"));
jobs.add(job0);
jobs.add(job1);
Comparator<Job> comparator = new Comparator<Job>() {
  @Override
  public int compare(Job o1, Job o2) {
    if (o1.getOrder() > o2.getOrder()) {
      return 1;
    }
    return 0;
  }
};
Collections.sort(jobs, comparator);
```

where:

```
public class Job {
  private String path;
  private List<String> targets;
  private final int order;
  public Job(String path, int order, List<String> targets) {
    this.path = path;
    this.order = order;
    this.targets = targets;
  }
 ...
  public int getOrder() {
    return order;
  }
}
```

I would like to simplify this. So I have tried:

```
public class Job implements Comparable<Integer> {
  private String path;
  private List<String> targets;
  private final int order;
  public Job(String path, int order, List<String> targets) {
    this.path = path;
    this.order = order;
    this.targets = targets;
  }
  public int compareTo(Integer o) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
  }
}
```

and

```
List<Job> jobs = new ArrayList<Job>();
Collections.sort(jobs);
```

But get:

```
Bound mismatch: The generic method sort(List<T>) of type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (List<Job>). The inferred type Job is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends Comparable<? super T>>
```

Is it possible to avoid passing a Comparator?

Comment: You need `Job` to implement `Comparable<Job>` (why did you make it implement `Comparable<Integer>`?).

Comment: It is a requirement that `a.compareTo(b) = -b.compareTo(a)` You must return -1 in the opposite situation to when you return +1 and vice-versa.

Comment: @PeterLawrey what could happen if you fail to? Just a broken sorting order?

Comment: @JanDvorak "tim sort" can detect this has happened and throw an exception. It might not detect an issue, in when case you get something which is not sorted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it like this :

```
public class Job implements Comparable<Job> { // a job is comparable to another job
  private String path;
  private List<String> targets;
  private final int order;
  public Job(String path, int order, List<String> targets) {
    this.path = path;
    this.order = order;
    this.targets = targets;
  }
  public int compareTo(Job j) {
    return this.order - j.order; // here you specify how you want your jobs sorted
  }
}
```

Comment: This is subject to integer overflow (OK, unlikely), you can use `Integer.compare()` instead.

Comment: its safer to use something like this.order>that.order? 1 : (this.order<that.order? -1 : 0) for fear of overflows

Comment: @radai just use `Integer.compare(order, j.order)` (no need for the `this` qualifier) which will do that for you

Comment: @fge Speaking of int and a variable called `order`, I wouldn't bother unless the order can get extreme values. But that's a useful remark so +1.

Comment: strange I don't have Integer.compare()

Comment: @u123 Not strange if you're on java 1.6 : it's a new method. But you really don't need it if your order doesn't get very very big.